# Is a POST request to an HTTPS endpoint using a NodeJS HTTP server vulnerable?

Tags: node.js, http, security, https

If I'm running a local `NodeJS` server over `http`, and I use `axios` or `request` to send a `POST` request to an `https` endpoint with a password as part of the data, is someone able to grab the password if they are monitoring network traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords served over HTTPS in POST data are secure. The fact that the origin of request is a Node.js application doesn't matter as the connection is still over the secure protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sorry, just to confirm though, my NodeJS server that *sends* the data is running on HTTP, the server that *receives* the data (a PHP server) is HTTPS. So your comment still stands, correct?

Comment: Sending a data doesn't need servers. The HTTP server is insecure but the request it initiates with HTTPS server is still secure. SO yes, my answer still stands.